# FTP download list of absolute paths

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I have a list of (a couple thousand) absolute paths to files on a remote server that I need to download to my PC.

I also need the files to keep the directory structure intact for those files.

**Example:**

```
/* UNIX Server File-System  */
/home/username/
    stuff/
    more-stuff/
    data/
    file1.txt

/* Local Windows File-System After Transfer  */
C:\Users\username\Documents\home\username\
    stuff\
    more-stuff\
    data\
    file1.txt
```

Ideally, I would use some type of FTP to get those files to my PC. However, I am unaware of a program or CLI command that supports getting a list of files. I need to get specific files from specific directories, I can't just download whole directories.

**My Question:** How can I use a list of absolute paths to automatically download the files to my localhost? (while keeping the directory structure intact)

Additionally, I have these files in a PHP array. So it is possible for me to export the list as JSON, CSV, XML, etc.

Comment: Can you use `rsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mind you can use `rsync` with something like

```
rsync -av --files-from=/path/yourlist.txt / remote:/backup
```

where in

- `/path/yourlist.txt`  you can put your list of files with the full path
- `/` The path to add to the filename in your list (If they are full pathname `/`)
- `remote:/backup` the remote host name and its relative path

You can read more searching for `--files-from` from the `man rsync` <sup>[[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)]</sup>

> **--files-from=FILE**
>
> ```
> Using this option allows you to specify the exact list of files to transfer (as
> read from the specified FILE or - for standard input). It also tweaks the 
> default  behavior of rsync to make transferring just the  specified files and 
> directories  easier:
> ```
>
> - The **--relative (-R) option is implied**, which preserves the path information that is specified for each item in the file (use --no-relative or --no-R if you want to turn that off).
> - The **--dirs (-d) option is implied**, which will create directories specified in the list on the destination rather than noisily skipping them (use --no-dirs or --no-d if you want to turn that off).
> - The --**archive (-a) option’s behavior does not imply --recursive (-r), so specify it explicitly, if you want it.**
> - These  side-effects  change  the  default  state  of  rsync,  so  the position of the --files-from option on the command-line has no bearing on how other options are parsed (e.g. -a works the same before or after
>     --files-from, as does --no-R and all other options).

... in the man page there is more...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Give a good look to the help... there are many interesting options e.g. to avoid to download again the same files, etc. etc...

Comment: Definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

`wget` has the functionality you are looking for. From the manpage:

```
-i file
       --input-file=file
           Read URLs from a local or external file.  If - is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input.  (Use ./- to read from a file literally named -.)
```

In other words: `wget -i filelist.txt`.

filelist doesn't necessarily have to be txt either, as wget supports html via the `--force-html` switch. If all you have is a list of directories/files, you can set the base URL on command line with the `--base` switch.

Comment: he said ftp, can you give an ftp example with wget?

Comment: @barlop The syntax is the same regardless of protocol. The only difference would be the contents of the filelist.txt, referencing the ftp protocol with the `ftp://` prefix

Comment: and the user/pass, it's worth including the url eg `"ftp://username:password@blah.xyz"`

Comment: This does not solve the problem fully, the OP stated **...while keeping the directory structure intact**. By using `wget`  you are placing all files in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am unaware of a program or CLI command that supports getting a list of files.

I am not sure why this should be a stumbling block. You can run `ftp` with a script as its source,

```
cd Target_Directory
ftp -v -s:script.ftp ftp.myhost.net 1> /absolute/path/to/my/logfile 2>&1
```

where `Target_Directory` is where you want to place the files about to be downloaded, and `script.ftp` is a script file like this:

```
USER MyUserId
MyPassword
cd SOURCE_DIR
binary
prompt n
mget the_first_file_I_need
mget the_second_file_I_need
bye
```

This is fine for *a single site*. How about many sites? You can create a script file, call it script_main, with the following lines:

```
cd Target_Directory_1
ftp -v -s:script_1.ftp ftp.myhost_1.net 1>> /absolute/path/to/my/logfile 2>>&1
cd Target_Directory_2
ftp -v -s:script_2.ftp ftp.myhost_2.net 1>> /absolute/path/to/my/logfile 2>>&1
....
```

and so on. You can prepare the `scrip_N.ftp` files by parsing the information you have into properly separated files.

Answer (score 2):

[aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) might be a possibility.

From the [documentation](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html) :

> **-d, --dir=**
>
> The directory to store the downloaded file.
>
> **-i, --input-file=**
>
> Downloads the URIs listed in FILE. You can specify multiple sources
>   for a single entity by putting multiple URIs on a single line
>   separated by the TAB character. Additionally, options can be specified
>   after each URI line. Option lines must start with one or more white
>   space characters (SPACE or TAB) and must only contain one option per
>   line. Input files can use gzip compression.

This would require to have a separate input-file per directory.